# iam trying program it shows errors

Tags: angular, typescript

it is hierarical inheritance in angularjs

iam trying but shows errors

```
import {SecondcomponentComponent} from './secondcomponent/secondcomponent.Component';
import {thirdcomponentcomponent} from './thirdcomponent/thirdcomponentcomponent';
this.newSecondcomponentComponent();
```

> ERROR in C:/myangpro/hieraricalinheritance/myproj30/src/app/app.component.ts (3,39): Cannot find module './thirdcomponent/thirdcomponentcomponent'.

> ERROR in C:/myangpro/hieraricalinheritance/myproj30/src/app/app.component.ts (16,9): Property 'newSecondcomponentComponent' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

Comment: I would start by reading the error messages. What is not clear about them? How you have tried to resolve them?

Comment: Also is this [tag:angular] or [tag:angularjs]? They are 2 very different frameworks.

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the rest of your code, but I suspect those are just typos.

Answer (score 0):

It may be directory issue or you havent imported your component in app.module.ts.

And Use @ViewChild() if you want to use a component withing another component

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that this has to do with spelling errors. But since I don't know about your project structure, this is a shot in the dark:

```
import {SecondcomponentComponent} from './secondcomponent/secondcomponent.Component';
import {ThirdcomponentComponent} from './thirdcomponent/thirdcomponent.Component';
let variable = new SecondcomponentComponent();
```